# How to set Primary keys in Sails js waterline database relationships

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have been studying relationships with sails JS waterline database from the official documentation. I however been having difficulty understanding how I am supposed to set my foreign keys just like I do in normal mysql relationships.
Please note that I have read the documentation here https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/associations before asking this question.

Let's say I have a model PersonalInfo.js

```js
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    fullName:{
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    phone:{
     type: 'string',
     required: true
   },

   location:{
     type: 'string',
     required: true
   },

   age:{
     type: 'integer',
     required: true
   },

   email:{
     type: 'string',
     required: true
   },

   gender:{
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  },

  userId:{
    type: 'integer',
    required: true,
  }
  
  },

};
```

And I have another model Archived.js which looks like this

```js
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    userId: {
      type: 'number',
      required: true,
      //unique: true,
    },
    comment:{
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    createdBy:{
      type: 'number',
      required: true
    }
    
  },

};
```

An archived item has a personalInfo. Knowing fully well that both models contain userId property, I want to fetch archived items with the related personalInfo like this, how do I relate the primary keys?

```js
var archived = Archived.find().populate('personal');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default sails will generate primary key `id` if you don't specify any.

If you want custom data as your primary key, you can override the `id` attribute in the model and give a `columnName`

```
id: {
  type: 'string',
  columnName: 'email_address',
  required: true
}
```

You can then find a record using:

```
await User.find({ id: req.param('emailAddress' });
```

[Reference](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings#?primarykey)

In your case, it seems like each `archived` has a `personalInfo`. So that's `one to one` from `archived` side, but, `one to many` from `personalInfo` side. To model these relationships, in sails you can do something like:

*personalInfo.js*

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {

    fullName:{
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },

    phone:{
     type: 'string',
     required: true
   },

   location:{
     type: 'string',
     required: true
   },

   age:{
     type: 'integer',
     required: true
   },

   email:{
     type: 'string',
     required: true
   },

   gender:{
    type: 'string',
    required: true
  },

  userId:{
    type: 'integer',
    required: true,
  },
  archives: {
    collection: 'archived',
    via: 'info'
  }

  },

};
```

*archived.js*

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    userId: {
      type: 'number',
      required: true,
      //unique: true,
    },
    comment:{
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    createdBy:{
      type: 'number',
      required: true
    },

    info: {
      model: 'personalinfo'  // sails works with small cases internally for models
    }

  },

};
```

Once you do this, creating an `archive` would be:

```
await Archive.create({
  ...

  // Set the User's Primary Key to associate the info with the archive.
  info: 123
});
```

Now you would finally be able to populate the `info` while querying.

`var archived = Archived.find().populate('info');`

Comment: thanks for reaching out. I just edited the question, I actually meant foreign key (my mistake) for relationships in database. I know that a primary key is automatically generated